# Different enums within another enum?

Tags: java, enums

The basics of what I am wondering is possible is whether or not I can store different enumerations (that all implement the same interface) as a value in an enumeration.

Here is an example I have set up (incorrectly, because I can't figure out how to do this if it is possible).

Colors.java (This is the main Enum to store the other enum)

```
public enum Colors {

WARM_COLORS(CoolColors), //Don't know what to put in here.
COOL_COLORS(WarmColors);

private Enum<? extends ColorIntf> colors; //Don't know if this is correct either

private Colors(Enum<? extends ColorIntf> colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
}

public Enum<? extends ColorIntf> getColors() {
    return this.colors;
}
}
```

ColorIntf.java (interface which the other enums implement)

```
public interface ColorIntf {
/**
 * @return The name of the color.
 */
public String getName();

}
```

WarmColors.java (one of the enums I wish to store as a variable in Colors.java, CoolColors.java is essentially the same but with different enum values)

```
public enum WarmColors implements ColorIntf{

RED("red"),
ORANGE("orange"),
YELLOW("yellow");

private String name;

private WarmColors(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see me.crystalneth.testing.ColorIntf#getName()
 */
@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

Here is the behavior I wish to achieve (this of course does not work at the moment):

```
Colors.WARM_COLORS.getColors().RED; //Allow the user to select the warm colors category, and limits them to a color only in that category.
```

The reason I want this type of behavior is because I am working on a project/lib where I want the user of it to be restricted to only certain enumeration values (colors in this case) of whatever category they choose (warm or cool colors in this case) to prevent errors that can happen if they, for example, choose "COOL COLORS" and "ORANGE" in this example.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What is wrong with `WarmColors.RED`? Why would you want the longer version of `Colors.WARM_COLORS.getColors().RED`?

Comment: Generally speaking, what you're going for isn't possible.  Many people have tried and failed do do something sensible here.  You're better off not encoding this in the type system.

Comment: @Andreas I am making a library that makes the basics of MySQL easy to use, so I have an enumeration called "SQLCharSet" which represents all character sets for MySQL. I want the user to select a charset from that, then be able to select a collation (since each char set has their own different collations). This behavior would ensure the user doesn't select a collation that doesn't correspond with the char set they selected.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Okay thank you. I guess I'll have to just  throw an exception if they choose a "color" that doens't match its "category".

Comment: Since collations are uniquely specific to a character set, why not just let user (by which you mean programmer) select a collation and infer character set from it? That way you can't select wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Thats gonna be a hell of a lot of re-doing things, but it seems like my best option. Thanks for the idea!